# spring Jpa is not recognizing the correct Entity name inside @Query param

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am facing a very wired issue.So need your input.

We have a common request-response library which is having 2 folder structure for 2 different Region:

```
com.test.aisa
com.test.europe
```

Both these packages are having common entity name Transaction.java ( as this is common across region.So, it has been created region specefic package structure inside the library ).

Now,we have 2 spring boot app.One for ASIA /one for EUROPE.

In my ASIA SPRING BOOTAPP app,I have written the TransactionRepository.java.
Here is the code:

```
public interface TransactionRepository  extends JpaRepository<com.test.asia.Transction,String>{


@Query("select ai from Transaction ai where ai.name : name")
Stream<Transction> findTransctionByName(@Param("name"));
```

}

Now the issue is  inside **@Query("select ai from Transaction ai where ai.name : name")**  it is pointing to **com.test.europe.Transaction.java**.

It is not recognizing the fields that are present as part of **com.test.aisa.Transaction.java.**

Eg name field is present the com.test.aisa.Transaction.java ,and not in europe version of it.
Rest every where it is pointing to correct Transaction entity.Only inside @Query ,it is creating issue.

Please help!!!!!!!
I  have never seen this kind of issue before.!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use full class name in the jpa Query:

```
@Query("select ai from com.test.asia.Transaction ai where ai.name = :name")
```

Comment: No, you normally don't need to specify the FQCN.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as following:

```
@Query("select ai from Transaction ai where ai.name= :name")
```

You have forgotten equal operator in where condition